# night vision by accumulating pictures

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

Would it be possible to recreate a mildly good image from combining multiple dark images using opencv. I know I can increase the contrast using histogram equalization and then do some gamma correction but cant seem to find a way to combine multiple dark images to create one good image.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://people.csail.mit.edu/yichangshih/time_lapse/).

Answer (score 2):

The problem with dark, i.e. under-exposed images, is that they are inherently noisy. There are so few photons actually arriving at the sensor during the exposure that the arrival of even one, stray photon of noise significantly impacts the recorded brightness, i.e. one photon of noise messes up the reading when it is so dark that only 2 photons are expected because it represents a 50% error in the expected reading of 2 when a total of 3 photons arrive. The situation is much better at the bright end of the histogram where many photons arrive and, in percentage terms, an additional stray, noisy photon makes little difference.

As noise is generally pretty random, image averaging is a legitimate technique to reduce it and improve your SNR. Basically, you average the pixels from multiple exposures at every  position in the image, and the result of averaging two exposures of, say ISO 800, is generally similar to an image exposed at ISO 400. In general, the magnitude of the noise, drops by the square root of the number of exposures averaged, so averaging 4 exposures decreases the magnitude of the noise by a half.

There is an excellent write-up [here](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/image-averaging-noise.htm) with images and theory. As for doing that in OpenCV, it is basically just a matter of adding the images up and dividing by the number of images.

Note that this technique is only applicable to STILL images, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice a bit different approach. Integrating image domain over time would be not the best idea if the camera is moving, or if there are moving objects in view, since that would introduce blurring.

Instead, you may try some image enhancement. I have recently discovered several approaches, namely [Retinex](http://dragon.larc.nasa.gov/aerospace/aerospace.html) and [CLAHE](http://projects.i-ctm.eu/en/project/enhancement-night-vision-images#slide-2-field_immagine-149). It turns out that even on noisy dark images there is enough information about the dark parts, it is just not in the range that is noticeable.

You can find retinex implementation in GIMP (source too), and CLAHE in OpenCV.

Both methods are rather fast, and can even be combined, to achieve more balanced results (retinex seems to overamplify noice sometimes on textureless regions, CLAHE can be tuned to avoid this, but generally has less impact on result than retinex)